# Get logs from all pods in namespace using xargs

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubectl

Is there anyway to get all logs from pods in a specific namespace running a dynamic command like a combination of awk and xargs?

```
 kubectl get pods | grep Running | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl logs | grep value
```

I have tried the command above but it's failing like `kubectl logs` is missing pod name:

> error: expected 'logs [-f] [-p] (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER]'.
> POD or TYPE/NAME is a required argument for the logs command
> See 'kubectl logs -h' for help and examples

Do you have any suggestion about how get all logs from Running pods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about what your pipeline is doing:

The `kubectl logs` command takes as an argument a *single* pod name, but through your use of `xargs` you're passing it *multiple* pod names. Make liberal use of the `echo` command to debug your pipelines; if I have these pods in my current namespace:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=name:.metadata.name
name
c069609c6193930cd1182e1936d8f0aebf72bc22265099c6a4af791cd2zkt8r
catalog-operator-6b8c45596c-262w9
olm-operator-56cf65dbf9-qwkjh
operatorhubio-catalog-48kgv
packageserver-54878d5cbb-flv2z
packageserver-54878d5cbb-t9tgr
```

Then running this command:

```
kubectl get pods | grep Running | awk '{print $1}' | xargs echo kubectl logs
```

Produces:

```
kubectl logs catalog-operator-6b8c45596c-262w9 olm-operator-56cf65dbf9-qwkjh operatorhubio-catalog-48kgv packageserver-54878d5cbb-flv2z packageserver-54878d5cbb-t9tgr
```

---

To do what you want, you need to arrange to call `kubectl logs` multiple times with a single argument. You can do that by adding `-n1` to your `xargs` command line. Keeping the `echo` command, running this:

```
kubectl get pods | grep Running | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 echo kubectl logs
```

Gets us:

```
kubectl logs catalog-operator-6b8c45596c-262w9
kubectl logs olm-operator-56cf65dbf9-qwkjh
kubectl logs operatorhubio-catalog-48kgv
kubectl logs packageserver-54878d5cbb-flv2z
kubectl logs packageserver-54878d5cbb-t9tgr
```

That looks more reasonable. If we drop the echo and run:

```
kubectl get pods | grep Running | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 kubectl logs | grep value
```

Then you will get the result you want. You may want to add the `--prefix` argument to `kubectl logs` so that you know which pod generated the match:

```
kubectl get pods | grep Running | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 kubectl logs --prefix | grep value
```

---

Not directly related to your question, but you can lose that `grep`:

```
kubectl get pods | awk '/Running/ {print $1}' | xargs -n1 kubectl logs --prefix | grep value
```

And even lose the `awk`:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase==Running -o name | xargs -n1 kubectl logs --prefix | grep value
```

Comment: Also, take a look at the [stern](https://github.com/wercker/stern) command.

Comment: I think that I can't use `uniq` in my pipeline in this case right? The `uniq` will be applied for each pod logs. Is there anyway to apply `uniq` after print all logs?

Comment: Something like: `kubectl get pods | grep Running | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 kubectl logs --prefix | grep value | uniq`

Comment: That works, sure (although depending on what you're looking for you may want to drop `--prefix`).

Comment: I am trying to extract outbound values using this command `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase==Running --no-headers | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 kubectl logs -c nginx | grep outbound | cut -d " " -f 17 | cut -d "|" -f 4 | uniq` .. it's almost working but I am seeing duplicated values because different pods logs, i think

Comment: Note that `uniq` only works on sorted values, so consider replacing `uniq` with `sort -u`.

Comment: You are savage, king of shell script! I was about to solve it using a conditional haha thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Just run below one liner

```
kubectl get pods -n default|grep -v NAME|awk '{print $1}'|while read pods;do kubectl logs $pods;echo;done|more
```